# Android: setOnClickListener for children of RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I use `RelativeLayout`

But children of this layout not work for settext , click and ...

How fixed it ?

> Code :

```
ImageView ImageView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
if (ImageView01 != null) {
    ImageView01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Log.i("error", "q" + 108);
       }
   });
}
```

This code for LinearLayout child of RelativeLayout

> XML :

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/lnrVideoControl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPlayVideo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_thin"
        android:thumbOffset="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If i use this code out of RelativeLayout worked full !

How fix this problem ?

Comment: How you are setting layout_weight for a child of RelativeLayout ? And remove clickable attribute from ImageView.

Comment: check the answer and let me know if it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have an ImageView with id `imgPlayVideo`. But you are creating reference to some other ImageView.

```
ImageView ImageView01 = findViewById(R.id.ImageView01)
```

This might be a wrong reference. So correct your code and refer to the exact ImageView

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgPlayVideo)
```

This might fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry, i change name of imageview. this code not work :(

Comment: Put a log inside your imageView null check and see if it is coming. Also change your layout_width to 0dp since you are using weight for a vertical oriented LinearLayout

Comment: This code also not work : TextView txtVideoEnd = (TextView) G.currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoEnd);
            txtVideoEnd.setText("123");

Comment: what is G.currentActivity ?

Comment: G.currentActivity = this;

Comment: your code looks to be vague, you are mentioning about RelativeLayout and I dint see any RelativeLayout there